# How do you enter a tab character in Textblock?

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, tabs

Is it possible to add a tab character into a textblock?
It's a textblock in Xaml, but i'm adding the text in code, so it has to be done there.
Is there any action like "Environment.NewLine", but for the "Tab" character?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Martin put it as answer and i'll accept, most suitable answer according to me, ChrW(9), so i'll upvote :)

Comment: Bala R's answer is as valid as mine, though, you did not specify the language! It might have been C# as well.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use the [`vbTab` constant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbtab.aspx) from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace.

Answer (score 14):

Or a more .Net-y way:

```
Convert.ToChar(Keys.Tab)
```

Comment: Indeed, there are lots of ways to do this. [`ControlChars.Tab`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.controlchars.aspx) is another option. But there's nothing wrong with using the `vbTab` constant. It's just as much .NET as everything else. The compiler output will be the same as the C# compiler with the `\t` escape.

Comment: @CodyGray I think Matt meant a way reusable / works across all .Net languages which can be useful habit to get into when interchanging between l.Net anguages regularly

Answer (score 11):

You can also use:

```
ControlChars.Tab
```

Comment: Looking at the other answers, this is a good alternative to anything else.

Answer (score 9):

Sure just use:

```
Chr(9)
```

Example:

```
TextBox1.Text = "hey" + Chr(9) + "you"
```

Comment: Chr(9) didn't do for me, it seems it changed to ChrW(9), but thanks for helping me get that.

Comment: Yep I agree - I just didn't know of that method